# Grepping twice using result of first Grep in Large file

Tags: grep

Am given a list if ID which I need to trace back a name in a file

file: ID contains

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

The ID are contained in a Large 2 GB file called result.txt

```
ABC=John,dhds,72828,73737,3939,92929
CDE=John,uubad,32424,ajdaio,343533
FG1=Peter,iasisaio,097282,iosoido
WER=Ann,97391279,89719379,7391739
result,**id=1**,iuhdihdio,ihwoihdoih,iuqhwiuh,ABC
result2,**id=2**,9729179,hdqihi,hidqi,82828,CDE
result3,**id=3**,biasi,8u9829,90u209w,jswjso,FG1
```

So I cat the ID file into a variable

I then use this variable in a loop to grep out the values to link back to the name using grep and cut -d from results.txt and output to a variable

so variable contains ABS CDE FG1

In the same loop I pass the output of the grep to perform another grep on results.txt, to get the name
 ie regrets file for ABC CDE FG1

I do get the answer but takes a long time is their a more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: it sounds like you're looking for `grep -Ff idList.txt OtherFiles ....` (also know as `fgrep -f ...`. Unless you really have single digit ID values in that file. single digits can match any single digit in a multi-digit number. Good luck.

Comment: Given the size of data and indexed query, any shell tool for characters stream processing will not perform adequately. I'd choose to convert the data to even SQLite and perform genuine SQL queries to get the expected result report. I recommend SQLite because it does not need to setup a server, runs on any system and is also user locally installable if not provided for the whole system.

Comment: A lot of what you said went right over my head. Let's start with the `id`'s. Are you saying that some lines in the large file will have substrings of the form `**id=<number>**`, and the name associated to an id is the last token on that line (after the last comma)? Then - what is the desired output? In your example, what should be shown in the output for the input ID's of 4, 5, 6?

Comment: Your question could do with some improvement and clarification. Are there really asterisks in your file or did you add them to highlight the field? Are there really just 5 or 6 IDs to search for, or thousands? Once you find the ID, is it the last field you want? What's a *"regrets"* file? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 2):

Making some assumptions about your requirement... ID's that are not found in the big file will not be shown in the output; the desired output is in the format shown below.

Here are mock input files - `f1` for the id's and `f2` for the large file:

```
[mathguy@localhost test]$ cat f1

1
2
3
4
5
6

[mathguy@localhost test]$ cat f2

ABC=John,dhds,72828,73737,3939,92929
CDE=John,uubad,32424,ajdaio,343533
FG1=Peter,iasisaio,097282,iosoido
WER=Ann,97391279,89719379,7391739
result,**id=1**,iuhdihdio,ihwoihdoih,iuqhwiuh,ABC
result2,**id=2**,9729179,hdqihi,hidqi,82828,CDE
result3,**id=3**,biasi,8u9829,90u209w,jswjso,FG1
```

Proposed solution and output:

```
[mathguy@localhost test]$ sed 's/.*/\*\*id=&\*\*/' f1 | grep -Ff - f2 |  \
>      sed -E 's/^.*\*\*id=([[:digit:]]*)\*\*.*,([^,]*)$/\1 \2/'

1 ABC
2 CDE
3 FG1
```

The hard work here is done by `grep -F` which might be just fast enough for your needs. There is some prep work and some clean-up work done by `sed`, but those are both on small datasets.

First we take the id's from the input file and we output strings in the format `**id=<number>**`. The output is presented as the fixed-character patterns to `grep -F` via the option `-f` (take the patterns from file, in this case from stdin, invoked as `-`; that is, from the output of `sed`).

After we find the needed lines from the big file, the final `sed` just extracts the id and the name from each line.

Note: this assumes that each id is only found once in the big file. (Actually the command will work regardless; but if there are duplicate lines for an id, your business users will have to tell you how to handle. What if you get contradictory names for the same id? Etc.)